# How does this pattern work?

Tags: calculus, summation

I know that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\,!}=e=\lim_{n \to \infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}
$$
but why
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)\,!} = \cosh(1)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)\,!} = \sinh(1)-1
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\,!} = e-2
$$
It seems that we can get various results by changing the starting value of k and the denominators.
My question is that is there a formula or a theorem to explain this pattern?

Comment: All of them can be derived from the universal one first, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k/k!=e^x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\cosh(1)=\frac{e^1+e^{-1}}{2}=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^k}{k!}=\frac12\sum_{k=2p=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(2p)!}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac1{(2p)!}$$

and by the same method we get the expression of $\sinh(1)$.

Comment: Thank you! But I still didn't get it. I'm a beginner on calculus. Could you explain more?

Comment: Notice that if $k$ is odd i.e. $k$ has the form $k=2p+1$ then $1+(-1)^k=1-1=0$ and if $k$ is even so $k=2p$ then $1+(-1)^k=2$ so we can write the sum only for the even value of $k$.

Comment: Ok. It seems $\frac{1}{e}=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k\,!}$, why is that?